# Poisson Process Notation: P(N(h) = 2) =P(N1(h) = 1; N2(h) = 1)

Tags: probability

This is from the book: Stochastic Processes by Sheldon Ross
Does the ";" sign mean conditional probability in the second part of the equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$P(A,B)=P(A;B)=P(A\cap B){}$$